# Too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

I'm working on an application which allows one to list movies as well edit, insert and delete them. In the db I have three tables (Movie, Genre and MovieGenre) and this problem is related to adding a genre to a movie (by adding to the table MovieGenre, which keeps tracks of the movies genres).

Below is the relevant code, as well as the thrown exception. I just can't figure out why I get this error message, because I use the right number of arguments as I can see it in the c# code when calling the sproc.

Can somebody see what's the problem here?

**Exception:**
Procedure or function usp_InsertMovieGenre has too many arguments specified.

**Exception Details:** System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function usp_InsertMovieGenre has too many arguments specified.

**c# code:**

```
public void InsertMovieGenre(MovieGenre movieGenre) {

    using (SqlConnection conn = CreateConnection()) {
        try {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_InsertMovieGenre", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = movieGenre.MovieID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@GenreID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Value = movieGenre.MovieGenreID;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieGenreID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            conn.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            movieGenre.MovieID = (int)cmd.Parameters["@MovieGenreID"].Value;
        }
        catch {
        }
    }
}
```

**sproc:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_InsertMovieGenre
@GenreID varchar(500),
@MovieID int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MovieGenre (GenreID, MovieID)
    VALUES (@GenreID, @MovieID);
END
GO
```

Comment: `@MovieGenreID` is not a parameter.

Comment: Where is the definition of @MovieGenreID in your store procedure?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Error becaue of this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MovieGenreID", SqlDbType.Int, 4).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

**to resolve  modify stored procdeurre**

sproc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_InsertMovieGenre
    @GenreID varchar(500),
    @MovieID int,
    @MovieGenreID int output

    AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MovieGenre (GenreID, MovieID)
        VALUES (@GenreID, @MovieID);
     SELECT @MovieGenreID = @@identity   
    END
    GO
```

Comment: Note that theres a big difference in `@@identity` and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE_IDENTITY-IDENT_C But it should make no difference in this case(hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

You have to add this output parameter to your Stored-Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_InsertMovieGenre
@GenreID varchar(500),
@MovieID int,
@MovieGenreID int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MovieGenre (GenreID, MovieID)
    VALUES (@GenreID, @MovieID);
    SELECT @MovieGenreID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
GO
```

- [Returning Data by Using OUTPUT Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004.aspx)
- [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line. Your Sproc only takes the first two parameters

```
cmd.Parameters
  .Add("@MovieGenreID", SqlDbType.Int, 4)
  .Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

edit: to get the id created you can use newId() I believe. Which looks to be your intent.